# Swap Three Numbers In Single Statement

Tags: c, logic

Is there any possiblty to swap three numbers in a single statement

Eg :

- a = 10
- b = 20
- c = 30

I want values to be changed as per the following list

```
a = 20
b = 30
c = 10
```

Can these values be transferred in a single line?

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: Yes Sergei It was asked in an interview

Comment: the interview question was not mentioning any programming language ?

Comment: Adding tag for cLanguage

Comment: I added my solution for General uses, for any programming language I think, I hope will be helpful, and thank you for your question, good for mind "sport" :)

Comment: Do the recruiters get the best professionals with this kind of questions? Incredible

Comment: this is a stupid interview question..

Comment: how can we still be asked this kind of question ? i hope for you that the recruiter does not make use of that kind of tricks into his code. if he does, fly away as fast as posible: it is 1. unreadable, 2. a nightmare to maintain, 3. slow, 4. not saving any space at all (the space saved by the missing 3 temporary variables is eaten by the additional code required).

Comment: You could well be missing the point of the question - not every question is meant to be answered literally as asked. It may well be to test a candidate's judgement and interpersonal skills when being handed a poorly thought out task.

Comment: Hey asker, next time but full info of tags from beginning ! not later !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another solution for this question.

You can use this in many languages like `C,C++ and Java`.

It will work for `float` and `long` also.

```
a=(a+b+c) - (b=c) - (c=a);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$ python
>>> a, b, c = 10, 20, 30
>>> print a, b, c
10 20 30
>>> a, b, c = b, c, a
>>> print a, b, c
20 30 10
```

Comment: There was no C in the original tag list.

Comment: @Sergei: Indeed.  But there is now.  Perhaps the answer should be deleted now the question has been clarified?

Answer (score 6):

This is a silly question.  But here is the only answer (so far) that is both well-defined C and truly a single line:

```
a ^= b, b ^= a, a ^= b, b ^= c, c ^= b, b ^= c;
```

Uses the [XOR swap algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm), correctly.

**Note:** This assumes that `a`, `b` and `c` are all of the same integer type (the question doesn't specify).

Comment: `double a = 10; char b = 20; int c = 30;` hehehe

Comment: @pmg: Ah, that's a fair point.  The OP didn't specify that they were all of the same type.

Comment: `int a = 10, b = 10, c = 10;`

Comment: @Alok: Ah, good point.  I would delete the answer, except I can't, because it's already been accepted.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, that's OK. As you said, it's a silly question.

Answer (score 5):

Solution in C#. Using xor swap `a` and `b` first. The result of the assignment is the assigned value, in this case `b` is the leftmost variable so it is return as a result of `(b ^= a ^ (a ^= b ^= a))`. Then swap `c` and the `b` [using the same algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm). :)

```
            int a = 10;
            int b = 20;
            int c = 30;
            c ^= (b ^= a ^ (a ^= b ^= a)) ^ (b ^= c ^= b);
```

Comment: Did you run this? In ruby that's invalid.

Comment: that's obviously not ruby... nor python either... there is only one kind of language flawed enough to allow assignment inside an expression: C or one of its (equally flawed) derivative.

Comment: I figured that, yes :-) But since ruby has the same operation, I tried it there. `(b ^= (a ^= (b ^= a))) ^= c`, what will be the result of left part? My feeling tells me it's value, not variable.

Comment: it was a broken c# :) I have fixed in now

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The question was tagged as C after almost everyone here suggested an answer. See the question comments. Language was not specified.

Comment: @PenchoIlchev: Ah, yes, I see.  Unfortunately, it won't let me remove my downvote unless you edit your answer...

Comment: I have edited it. By the way, interested to know why it doesn't work in C. The XOR operator exists and should work the same way. The assignment is evaluated to the new value of the leftmost operand. strange

Comment: @PenchoIlchev: C (and C++) have the concept of [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_points).  Modifying a variable multiple times in between sequence points leads to undefined behaviour.  In your code, there are only two sequence points: before and after the entire expression.

Answer (score 4):

Make use of the comma operator ...

```
a = 10;
b = 20;
c = 30;
/* one statement */
tmp = a, a = b, b = c, c = tmp; /* assumes tmp has been declared */
assert(a == 20);
assert(b == 30);
assert(c == 10);
```

Comment: +1: Only correct answer so far.  But for a truly grim answer, you could combine comma operator with XOR swap, to eliminate `tmp`.  `a ^= b, b ^= a, a ^= b, b ^= c, c ^= b, b ^= c;`...

Comment: Assumes ! what if not declared ! that will make your code 2 lines (in some programming languages) not single , and question is clear you have these 3 numbers ! to swap in 3 variables.

Comment: @Al-Mothafar: nevertheless it works with these definitions: `int a = 10; double b = 20; char c = 30;` and the declaration `float tmp;`. No other suggestion does it.

Answer (score 3):

Um, I like these logic things, my solution:

```
a= b+c-((b=c)+(c=a))+c;
```

BTW: I tested that (Actually using JS) and working with any numbers :)

**Edit**:

I tested with negative & decimals and working too :)

Comment: -1: Unspecified Behaviour ... the sub-expression evaluation order is not specified.

Comment: The compiler can choose to do the sub-expressions in any order it likes: for example it can do `(c=a)` before `(b=c)` which would make `b` get assigned the value in `a`.

Comment: I think question asked for logic not for compiler for specific language ! what works in programming language not always work on another one at the same way ! in logic question you need to answer in correctly at your view !

Comment: the question is tagged with `C`. I assume a C answer is expected. It's the rules of C that make it unspecified (not any compiler). See [the C11 Standard, section 6.5](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: OK, tagged with C after edit, and I put my answer before that edit ! So You cant be hurry and put your rude comments like YaY I'm Genius and you all stupids !

Comment: I don't think my comment is a rude comment. It simply states that I found the answer not useful (by the -1) and a fact (unspecified behaviour) to *somehow* justify the unusefulness and maybe make it a better answer overall.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for including the Tag later.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify the language, I will pick one of my choice. It's Ruby.

```
sergio@soviet-russia$ irb
1.9.3p0 :001 > a = 10
 => 10 
1.9.3p0 :002 > b = 20
 => 20 
1.9.3p0 :003 > c = 30
 => 30 
1.9.3p0 :004 > a, b, c = b, c, a # <== transfer is happening here
 => [20, 30, 10] 
1.9.3p0 :005 > a
 => 20 
1.9.3p0 :006 > b
 => 30 
1.9.3p0 :007 > c
 => 10
```

Comment: There was no C in the original tag list.

Comment: Indeed.  But there is now.  Perhaps the answer should be deleted now the question has been clarified?

Answer (score 0):

Try Different scenario:
 Eg :

```
a = 10
b = 20
c = 30

a= a+b+c;
b=a-b-c;
c=a-b-c;
a=a-b-c;
```

For `n` number's,

```
a = 10
b = 20
c = 30
.
.
.
n


a= a+b+c+......+n;
b=a-b-c-.......-n;
c=a-b-c-.......-n;
.
.
.
n=a-b-c-.......-n;
a=a-b-c-.......-n;
```