# How compilers evaluate mathematical expressions?

Tags: java, c, compiler-construction

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635686/swap-three-numbers-in-single-statement) question and then I made the following.

```
a = b + (c - (b = c)) + (a - (c = a))
```

I tried that in C and Java. It works with java , but not C.

Of course, it depends on how the compiler evaluate such expressions and after googling about that, I failed to find the answer.

Comment: Compilers doesn't evaluate such expressions (well, it *may* if they're constant, but it must not make a difference). It merely produces roughly equivalent code in another language (JVM bytecode in the case of `javac`, machine code for your processor in the case of `gcc`, `cl.exe`, etc.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work in C is because C doesn't specify exactly when the `c = a` will occur. It can occur before or after the two other times it is referenced in that statement.

So depending on when the compiler decides to perform the assignment `c = a`, the value of the expression will vary. It's not defined.

i.e. If `b = c`  is evaluated before `c = a` then, `b` will take the original value of `c`. If it is evaluated after, then it will take the value of `a`.

Comment: Worse, as this is undefined, anything could happen. For instance reading something which is neither the old nor the new value. (This could be understandable for a 64 bit value on a 32 bit machine where writing the new value need two instructions)

Comment: That's a good point about the 64-bit value on 32-bit. I've never thought about that. (Granted, I prefer to avoid undefined behavior in the first place rather than try to reason out what will happen.)

Comment: @Mystical, I agree about avoiding UB, but I find it easier to remember it is UB instead of simply not specified if I understand why an implementation could behave strangely.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the java [expressions document](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html) for the perfect answer.

Comment: That could only specify how it works in Java. It can't explain why it works differently in C.